# Serializing list of objects with flexjson

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-endpoints, flexjson

I am playing with `flexjson` and `Google Cloud Endpoints`. My model which I need to serialize is:

```
public class SampleModel {
 Long id;
 DateTime createdAt;
 String message;
 OtherModel other;
}
```

I just created `DateTimeObjectFactory` to find a way of creating `DateTime` objects (lacks of no arg constructor). Now I have question about `OtherModel` and `SampleModel` as well.

I want to serialize in fact a `List` of `SampleModel`. So here is my code:

```
List<SampleModel> sampleList = new ArrayList<SampleModel>();
// ...
// adding some items to sampleList
// ...
String s = new JSONSerializer().deepSerialize(sampleList);
```

I want to `deepSerialize` it for now to avoid some unserializated fields, but just for now.

When I want to deserialize `s` I do that:

```
sampleList = new JSONDeserializer<List<SampleModel>>()
    .use("other", OtherModel.class)
    .use(DateTime.class, new DateTimeObjectFactory())
    .deserialize(s);
```

I think that everything is just ok in that kind of deserializing, because I can see in logs deserialized object. But in fact when I want to get item from that new `sampleList` I get an error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to com.test.games.testapi.model.SampleModel
```

If I have good understanding every not trivial object will be deserialized as `Map` if I don't point the right class to deserializer. So this error means that script didn't know `SampleModel`? What is the meaning of this?

Comment: What happens if you try it with .use("values", SampleModel.class)

Comment: Read include/excludes part in this [flexjson.sourceforge](http://flexjson.sourceforge.net/) you could get some idea.